# change "We can't find products matching the selection" massage in magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, localisation

I'd like to change this message to **'We can't find products matching the selection'** and **'You don't subscribe to our newsletter'** default massages.

Can anyone suggest how this can be done in Magento 2.1?

Answer (score 1):

**You have to just create i18n folder in your theme root.
Create en_US.csv file underneath i18n folder.**

```
app/design/frontend/{Packagename}/{themename}/i18n/en_US.csv
"You don\'t subscribe to our newsletter.","Pass here your custom message"
"We can\'t find products matching the selection.","Pass your custom message string"
```

Set your default string and translated string in csv file.

run command, `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
**clear cache.**

Comment: i tried it ,and changed ran php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy and clear cache multiple times and still changes are not reflected .

Comment: please show your path of csv file

Comment: app/design/frontend/{Packagename}/{themename}/i18n/en_US.csv i tried translate inline feature and it worked , Thx